# Swift UICollectionView Navigation Bar Constraint

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

How would I move the UICollectionView beneath my created Navigation bar?

**Created Navigation Bar Code**

```
func addNavigationbar() {
    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! - 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.view.addSubview(navBar)

        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "")
        self.searchController = searchControllerWith(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar

        navBar.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make any changes to the navbar to give it such an unusual height?

Comment: How to do move the screen beneath the navigation bar?

Comment: By the looks of it, you are adding another navbar to your existing VC (That already has a nav bar)

Comment: yes that is how it looks

Comment: I am just curious. Do you know the answer to the question or just chatting about the view?